# Force ellipsis to print an end of an expression

Tags: output-formatting, syntax

For pedantic reasons I want to display an infinite sum of fractions in fractional form (i.e. as 1/x not as x^(-1))  with an ellipsis at the end of the expression. I have tried a number of ways and none seem to give me what I want. For example

```
HoldForm[1/#^s] & /@ Table[3^n, {n, 1, 4}]
{1, %, \[Ellipsis]} // Flatten
(Plus @@ %) // TraditionalForm
```

gives me output ordered as: **fractional forms + ... + 1**, while StandardForm gave me **1 + ... + the fractional forms**.  Other ways I tried led to similar forms - none of them yield the book form of **1 + fractions + ...** that I want.

I am probably missing something simple here - Thank you for any help

Answer (score 5):

One way to display the sum in the order you want is to use `Row`:

```
HoldForm[1/#^s] & /@ Table[3^n, {n, 1, 4}]
{1, %, ...} // Flatten
Row[%, "+"] // TraditionalForm
```

> $1+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{9^s}+\frac{1}{27^s}+\frac{1}
>    {81^s}+\ldots$

The reason why the order isn't maintained in the original version is that `Plus` has attribute `Orderless` which means that the order is arbitrary and will by default be determined "lexicographically".

**Edit**

If you prefer to get the display in `HoldForm` (which you were already using), another alternative is this:

```
HoldForm[1/#^s] & /@ Table[3^n, {n, 1, 4}]
{1, %, ...} // Flatten
TraditionalForm[% /. List[x__] :> HoldForm[Plus[x]]]
```

Here I use a replacement rule to change the `List` to `Plus` while leaving it inside `HoldForm` so that there is no evaluation and re-ordering.